# Почему я не могу получить из request изображения?

Tags: python, html, django, django-template

У меня есть список учеников, и нужно каждому добавить фото и одной кнопкой сохранить все изображения. Но изображения не отправляются. В чем может быть дело? Пока показываю код html-страницы. При необходимости могу показать views. Но по тестами поняла, что просто изображения не передаются

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>All Students</title>
    <style>
        body {
            font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
            background-color: #f8f9fa;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }
        h1 {
            color: #007bff;
            text-align: center;
            margin-bottom: 30px;
        }
        table {
            width: 80%;
            margin: 0 auto;
            border-collapse: collapse;
            background-color: #fff;
            border-radius: 5px;
            box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
        }
        th, td {
            padding: 10px;
            border: 1px solid #dee2e6;
        }
        th {
            background-color: #007bff;
            color: #fff;
            text-align: left;
        }
        tr:nth-child(even) {
            background-color: #f8f9fa;
        }
        tr:hover {
            background-color: #e9ecef;
        }
        input[type="file"] {
            margin-right: 10px;
        }
        .button-container {
            text-align: center;
            margin-top: 20px;
        }
        .save-button {
            background-color: #28a745;
            color: #fff;
            border: none;
            padding: 10px 30px;
            border-radius: 4px;
            cursor: pointer;
            transition: background-color 0.3s;
        }
        .save-button:hover {
            background-color: #218838;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>All Students</h1>
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Фамилия</th>
                <th>Имя</th>
                <th>Добавить работу</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            {% if students %}
                {% for student in students %}
                <tr>
                    <td>{{ student.last_name }}</td>
                    <td>{{ student.first_name }}</td>
                    <td>
                        <form action="{% url 'create_work' type_work.id %}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                            {% csrf_token %}
                            <input type="hidden" name="student_id" value="{{ student.id }}">
                            <input type="file" name="image_work">
                        </form>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                {% endfor %}
            {% else %}
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="3">Нет учеников в данном классе</td>
                </tr>
            {% endif %}
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <div class="button-container">
        <form action="{% url 'create_work' type_work.id %}" method="post">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <button type="submit" class="save-button">Сохранить работы</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: у вас кнопка "сохранить работы" относится только к самой последней форме в самом низу html-файла, а данные учеников выводятся в многократных формах, которые потом никак не обрабатываются..  вам нужно объединить всё в одну форму, ввести в ней данные и потом отправить.

Comment: спасибо за помощь и исправления)))